# Prove: if matrix $A=A^k$ for $k\geq 2\implies\ker A\cap\operatorname{Im} A=\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I think that $\ker A\cap\operatorname{Im} A=\{0\}$ is just a confusing way to say that: $\dim(\ker A)=0$ but not sure how to start.

Comment: No it is not equivalent to $\dim(\ker A)=0$. For example, a projector on a straight line (thus $P^2=P$) has an hyperplane as its kernel, far from being $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $v\in \operatorname{Im}A\cap \ker A$, so $Av=0$ and $v=Aw$ for some $w$. Then $v=Aw=A^kw=A^{k-1}v=A^{k-2}0=0$